# How do I search LDAP for employees allowing partial dn or uo matches?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

One more LDAP question for the pile.

tl;dr

Here is an example dn of and employee I would like to find:

```
CN=ID304397,OU=Personal,OU=UnitedStates,OU=Department,DC=ad,DC=companyName,DC=net
```

I would like to find all employees whose DNs contain the values `OU=Personal`, `DC=ad`, `DC=companyName`, and `DC=net` and `givenName=Name*` while allowing additional OUs and DCs.

Example DN of desired found employees

```
CN=ID30434,OU=Personal,OU=Africa,OU=Department,DC=ad,DC=companyName,DC=net
CN=ID1234,OU=Personal,OU=Hawaii,OU=OtherDepartment,DC=additionalDc,DC=ad,DC=companyName,DC=net
```

More details:

Using Softerra LDAP Administrator I've tried searching the following DNs using the following filters

- Search DN `DC=ad,DC=companyName,DC=net`
- Filter `(&(ou=Personal)(objectClass=user)(givenName=Name*))`

and

- Search DN `OU=Personal,DC=ad,DC=companyName,DC=net`
- Filter `(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=Name*))`

among other things that also found nothing.

I do not want to resort to removing the ou clause and filtering on the front-end after I get query results.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be broken down into two trivial components:

1. Query the domain for all Organizational Units named `Personal`:

   - Search base DN: `DC=ad,DC=wedani,DC=net`
   - Query filter: `(&(ou=Personal)(objectClass=organizationalUnit))`
2. For each OU discovered in step 1:

   - Query for users under that OU:

     - Search base DN: `<distinguishedName of OU>`
     - Query filter: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=Name*))`

For all requests, you'll want to scope the queries to `subtree` (eg. recursively search any container under the base DN)

Comment: So there must be logic on the LDAP calling side. Meh.

Comment: @DrFloyd5 Correct, there's nothing in AD or the LDAP specification that'll let you do this as a single concise LDAP query.